# Multiple interrelated loops in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, subquery, correlated-subquery

Loop1 is derived through some easy logic. Loop2 is derived through a very complex logic. Loop3 is very simple is just derived by adding 2 to Loop2

Now, I want to derive Loop4 through the combination of Loop1, Loop2 & Loop3. The problem is that loop2 is a very heavy logic and query is running very slow if I derive the logic again inside Loop3. To provide more clarity, I am finding loop3 using loop1&2 and loop4 using loop1,2&3. Please suggest a way to get this query work.

```
select sre.shipmentId, 
       loop1.TRY1, 
       loop2.TRY2, 
       loop3.TRY3, 
       (select case when u>0 then loop1.TRY1 when u>1 then loop2.TRY2 else loop3.TRY3 end) as loop4
from `shipmentRouteEvent` sre
left join (select sre1.shipmentId as s1, (case when .....>0 then .... end) ad TRY1
           from `shipmentRouteEvent` sre1
           where sre1.updateDate='2013-07-01'
          ) as loop1 on sre.id=try1.id
left join (select some heavy logic which will modify TRY1 to TRY2) as loop2
left join (select (TRY2+2) as TRY3) as loop3
where sre.updateDate='2013-07-01'
```

Comment: It is highly doubtful that you need this many left joins (if any at all), to accomplish this logic.  Can you provide more detail on the algorithm that determines `TRY` as well as the 'heavy logic' that determines `TRY2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this as nested subqueries:

```
from (select . . .
      fro (select . . .
           from `shipmentRouteEvent` sre left join
                 (select sre1.shipmentId as s1, (case when .....>0 then .... end) ad TRY1
                  from `shipmentRouteEvent` sre1
                  where sre1.updateDate='2013-07-01'
                ) loop1
                on sre.id=try1.id
           ) loop1 left join
           (select some heavy logic which will modify TRY1 to TRY2
           ) loop2
           on . . .
      ) loop2 left outer join
      (. . .
      ) loop3
      on . . .
```

Each level of nesting will allow you to use the results at the next level, so the results do not need to be recalculated.